# Two functions returning observable; need to conditionally call one based on result of the other

Tags: typescript, rxjs, observable, reactive-programming

I am a complete newbie in TypeScript and reactive programming (RxJS library, specifically) and I think I am fundamentally missing something because I cannot figure out how to implement my use case.

Contex of my use case is as follows. I have code written in TypeScript which I inherited. The code includes two functions: foo1 and foo2. Both functions perform some relatively long operations and return an object of type "Observable". I cannot modify these two functions. I need to write a new function which returns an Observable and does the following:

- Calls function foo1.
- If foo1 succeeds, calls function foo2 and returns whatever that function returns.
- If foo1 fails, returns an Observable which resolves to an error.

Is it possible at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

return foo1().mergeMap(foo1Result => foo2());

Comment: This may be the correct answer, but as the asker is a newbie, it would be helpful to provide some explanation of why this will work

Comment: This is actually what I was looking for! I knew it must be something very simple! :) Other answers are useful too. Thanks, all!

I have one question though. What would be different if I replace "mergeMap" with "flatMap"? Running my test code, I didn't see difference.

Comment: flatMap is an alias for mergeMap. mergeMap is the "official" name of the method, but I'm used to "flatMap" from earlier implementations / other languages, and prefer that.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose you have `first(): Observable<{succeed: boolean, error: error, value: any}>` and `second(): Observable<...>`

```
first.pipe(
  mergeMap((ret) => 
     ret.succeed ? second(ret.value) : Observable.throw(ret.error)
   )
)
```

Comment: Thank you, this is a good answer too. My first function throws an exception when it fails, so the answer suggested by GreyBeardedGeek is sufficient, but if the first function was returning the error as a boolean flag, I suppose your solution would be the way to go. I was able to verify it's working too.

Comment: ideally both answer are actually same. it's just different illustration.

Answer (score 0):

You need to chain the two calls if the first gives an error the second one will not execute. See the following example

```
  callDataService1(){
    this.dataService.getData1()
      .subscribe(data =>
      { this.myData = data, this.callDataService2()},
        error => this.errorMessage = error);
    }
    callDataService2(){
     this.dataService.getData2()`
      .subscribe(data =>
      { this.myData2 = data},
        error => this.errorMessage = error);
    }
```

Hope it helps. I do like that when need a data from a call to make another one

Comment: I assume callDataService1() will be the new function I had to come up with. The problem is it does not seem to return anything. But it needs to return an observable.

Comment: getData1 and getData2 both are funcions on my service that return observables. The example Its using services on an angular component,  the idea Its the same if you dont use angular

Answer (score 0):

You can use [switchMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/switchmap.html) which will call your first observable then switch to the second (cancelling the first). If your first observable `foo1` errors, the second is not called. In your `subscribe` method, the second parameter takes the error callback.

Note: the second parameter of `switchMap` takes a selector function, which allows you to combine the emitted outer observable value and the inner value: `f1, f2) => ({ f1, f2 })`
Here is an example:

Also, if the requirement is for `foo1` to continually emit, then replace `switchMap` with [flatMap](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/selectmany.md) in the example.

```js
    const foo1 = () => {
        return Rx.Observable.of({ id: 'foo1' }); 
    }

    const foo2 = () => {
        console.log('calling foo2');
        return Rx.Observable.of({ id: 'foo2' }); 
    }

    foo1()
        .switchMap((f1) => foo2(), (f1, f2) => ({ f1, f2 }))
        .subscribe(combined => console.log(combined), err =>console.error(err) );
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@reactivex/rxjs@5.5.6/dist/global/Rx.js"></script>
```

Here is an example where `foo1` errors, you will notice `foo2` doesn't get called.:

```js
const foo1 = () => {
    return Rx.Observable.throw('bad foo!')
}

const foo2 = () => {
    console.log('calling foo2');
    return Rx.Observable.of({ id: 'foo2' }); 
}

foo1()
    .switchMap((f1) => foo2(), (f1, f2) => ({ f1, f2 }))
    .subscribe(combined => console.log(combined), err =>console.error('>>err',err) );
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@reactivex/rxjs@5.5.6/dist/global/Rx.js"></script>
```